# MJML edm how to make a column's height same as the other column?

Tags: email, html-email, mjml

I am trying to achieve the following design on my EDM:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
<mj-section
    padding="12px 48px 12px"
    background-color="#FFF"
>

    <mj-column width="50%">
        <mj-image
            src="assets/img/image-1.png"
            width="231px"
            padding="0"
            align="center"
        />
    </mj-column>

    <mj-column width="50%" background-color="#F0F0F0">
        <mj-text
            color="#101010"
            font-size="29px"
            line-height="35px"
            font-family="Arial, sans-serif"
            font-weight="700"
            align="right"
            padding="0"
        >
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </mj-text>
    </mj-column>

</mj-section>
```

but I am getting not my desired result:

[image]

How can I make the 2nd column's height fill the whole section to equal the height of the other column?

Hope somebody can help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the whole row (or both columns) the same background color

```
<mj-section
padding="12px 48px 12px"
background-color="#fff">

<mj-section
background-color="#F0F0F0">

<mj-column width="50%" background-color="#F0F0F0">
    <mj-image
        src="assets/img/image-1.png"
        width="231px"
        padding="0"
        align="center"/>
</mj-column>

<mj-column width="50%" background-color="#F0F0F0">
    <mj-text
        color="#101010"
        font-size="29px"
        line-height="35px"
        font-family="Arial, sans-serif"
        font-weight="700"
        align="right"
        padding="0"
    >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </mj-text>
</mj-column>
</mj-section>
</mj-section>
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: What if you change the color for the section? (just edited code)

Comment: Are you able to put a section inside a section? Check out the code updated above

Comment: Don't be afraid to edit the code or try new things (as long as you have a backup). Email coding is fun!

Comment: Sections cannot be nested inside each other, as per official docs https://mjml.io/documentation/#mjml-section